# aws cli equivalent of pipe: atlassian/aws-ecs-deploy in bitbucket.yml

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a bitbucket yml file that I need to covert to a shell script, How do I convert a atlassian/aws-ecs-deploy pipe to aws command line?

I have the following pipe

```
      pipe: atlassian/aws-ecs-deploy:1.6.2
      variables:
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
        AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
        CLUSTER_NAME: '${AWS_CLUSTER_NAME}'
        SERVICE_NAME: '${AWS_SERVICE_NAME}'
        TASK_DEFINITION: 'task-definition.json'
```

I tried looking at the source but am not familiar with python. The source is at https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/aws-ecs-deploy/src/master/

Answer (score 0):

The pipe uses common methods from AWS' Python SDK, boto3, and there is an equivalent AWS CLI command for any of those (it is actually built on top of it)

The pipe boils down to conditionally running some of the following instructions

```
aws ecs register-task-definition \
    --container-definitions task-definition.json
aws ecs update-service \
    --force-new-deployment \
    --cluster ${AWS_CLUSTER_NAME} \
    --service ${AWS_SERVICE_NAME}
aws ecs wait services-stable \
    --cluster ${AWS_CLUSTER_NAME} \
    --services ${AWS_SERVICE_NAME}
```

plus overcoming all the authentication boilerplate.